# Facebook's Open Graph scraper slow to fetch og:image?

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, facebook-opengraph

**Context**

I'm running a site over https where new content (each entry has its own page) can be created and shared by users.

Each page has an image, and this image url is present in the `og:image` meta tag at the top of the page.

**Problem**

Facebook seems slow to pick up on the `og:image`. When the page is first created and a user attempts to share the URL, for the first ~1-3 tries, the `og:image` is not scraped / rendered by Facebook (the title and description are). Afterwards, the image is clearly visible in the share dialog.

A similar issue also occurs when using Facebook's OG URL debug tool. The first time I pop in the URL, it shows no image. If I choose to fetch the page from the source again, it shows the image.

**Additional Notes**

At first, I thought it might have been site code initially not showing the image, but I sent a curl request and spoofed one of Facebook's user agent strings (this is important to accessing the page) and the resulting HTML contains the `og:image` tag with the correct image URL. I also know it's not anything to do with accessing the page, or the `og:title` and `og:description` data would not be showing (but it is).

My only lead is that it could be an SSL or HTTPS issue. I recently set up the SSL certificate but I'm not sure why that would cause a delay over it not working at all.

For the sake of clarity, the site runs on WordPress on top of a standard LAMP stack.

Comment: Facebook has its own rules for caching / scraping pages. AFIK those rules aren't public. I do know that visiting an object with the debugger forces a refresh of the FB cache. Not sure if you could implement something on your backend when you create an object to force this refresh without running afoul of the FB TOS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is apparently a fairly common one. The solution was to, on content creation, send a request to facebook's scraper tool with the content's URL. The scraper will pick up and process the image, allowing the first share to already have that image cached by Facebook.

Comment: Could you give an example of request with image to facebook scraper tool?

Comment: Is it this tool? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Apologies @valentin, this was quite a few years ago and I no longer use Facebook (and therefore cannot access the URL). AFAIK this used to be a public service so you could do this without needing any kind of auth.
Essentially you would input a URL and the tool would collect & display the OG metadata, caching the preview image as a byproduct. I'm no longer sure that this is a supported method to do this any more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've noticed this as well. It takes a long time for Facebook to cache the og:image. Tumblr does it automatically. The only reason why I could imagine why Facebook does this other than poor programming is because perhaps they have a review team scrolling through the thumbnails to block nudity and other crude images. As mentioned above, clicking the facebook share url manually upon creation will prompt them to cache it, hopefully before others click too.

Answer (score 0):

I have been analyzing this issue one year ago. I had the same problem. The  `og:image` meta tag has been only updated after several rescrape attempts.
This re-scraping can be easily triggered on this page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

According to my old analysis, the root cause of this behavior is that the FB scraper seems to have a very very short timeout. If the content page does not reply to the scraper request very quickly, FB doesn't take this reply into account. Even if the content page serves the correct meta data and a valid HTTP/200 reply, FB ignores it because "too late is too late".

I didn't find any solution for this besides "prescraping" as has been already described by Sean.

Answer (score 0):

In My Case I had a azure WebApp with HTTPS setup without SSL Certificate installed. As It was in Production stage, I tested by reverting back to HTTP. All "og" tags were detected.
So, If your SSL is not properly configured and/or Facebook gives CURL SSL Error, looking into SSL might help.